# LabView playing more than one sound at the time

Tags: audio, labview

I'm using event structure and want to do some like Launchpad.
Numeric keyboard have for each number added a sound.
Problem is, that when I press number example one, the program is waiting when the music stop play and next I can press example number four.

Is it possible, to play sounds from 3 key's at the same time using event structure ?

[I put the files online here](http://www.filedropper.com/dziala) and added screenshots below. Block diagram:

[image: block diagram]

Front panel:

[image: front panel]

Comment: How are you generating the sounds? With a VI inside of the event case, or are you calling some outside program?

Comment: I'm generating the sound using structure where I can load wav files. We can say that its Vi.

Comment: Can you please show us a screen shot of the code that generates the sound for a key? Do you have different cases of your event structure handling different keys (and playing different sounds)? In general, if you want to get the most out of your question, you need to provide an example of code that reproduces the problem so that we can run it and try to help you. Check out the [help center page on asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: I just uploaded the file. Thank You for showing help center page, I hope that help me to creating more matching and better prepared questions in future.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot instead? You can add a picture by clicking on the "add image" icon when editing your post and then dragging and dropping the picture into the box that pops up. I am reluctant to download files from unknown sources.

Comment: Screenshot Added, because my reputation is low, I only can add two links.   Here is front : http://i.stack.imgur.com/FeOIy.jpg

Comment: Cool, thanks! I added the second screenshot for you. What one of the answer says about blocking I/O is correct, but we might be able to get around it. Let me test some things and see if I can work around it.

Comment: I think I got it working for you. Check out my answer and let me know if it isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working Solution

I think I got this working much more easily than I expected using the [`Play Sound File`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvpict/playsoundfile/) VI under the `Graphics and Sound -> Sound -> Output` palette. That link is the 2011 documentation (couldn't find a more recent link), but it does not look like it has changed. The working result is shown below, with two different events handled by the event structure:

`Key Down?` event:

[image]

`Stop Button` event:

[image]

You may be fine without using the `Sound Output Clear` VI to the right of the main event loop, but having it there won't hurt.

It turns out that the `Play Sound File` VI does not block, so you can play multiple overlapping sound files. If you run into blocking on your machine (one sound file plays, then the next, and so on), let me know because I have another solution that might work.

### A word on events

An important thing to understand is that events are handled in a queue. When you press keys, those key presses go *in order* onto the event queue. Each time your event-handling loop executes, it takes the *oldest* event out of that queue and processes it. The event structure in LabVIEW will only handle one event per iteration of your event-handling loop. On the next iteration, if events are still in the queue that your structure is set up to process, it will take the next-oldest one for that iteration and repeat.

Now, lets say that you want to do some super complicated processing that takes 10 seconds every time you press a key, and you put that processing inside of your main event loop. Your key presses still go onto the event queue as fast as you press them, but LabVIEW has to wait the full 10 seconds before it can dequeue the next keypress and process it, so you end up with an application that seems to hang while it chugs through the queue much slower than you are adding items to the queue.

One way to get around this is to take that complicated processing and put it outside of the queue in another process. If you have the resources, you can actually call a separate instance of a processing sub-VI in its own thread for every one of those key presses. This allows the event handling loop to spawn processes as fast as you can press keys, and then your processes take whatever time they need to *simultaneously* (resources permitting) perform whatever actions you wanted.

Essentially that is what the `Play Sound File` VI is doing. It sees that you want to play a file and spawns a process to play that sound over the speakers, allowing the event-handling loop to continue immediately rather than waiting for the sound to finish playing. As you press more keys, more processes get spawn that kill themselves when they are finished. You can do this manually too, which is the other solution that I have for you if `Play Sound File` does not behave the same way for you as it did for me.

Comment: In Play Sound File dunno why, I have error "Cannot recognize sound format." Tomorrow I will try to solve this problem and give You feedback if this solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The sounds which Im using are wav files, even from Windows media library are not working.

Comment: Error 4810: LabVIEW:  (Hex 0x12CA) Cannot recognize sound format.

Comment: Solved. To solve this problem, install 32-bit version  of LabView. Working great and this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Thanks to @Engineero for pointing out that Play Sound File vi actually isn't blocking. The updated code shows how to play overlapping sounds. I'll leave it to the user to add the Stop Sound on Key Up code. No timeout is needed because nothing is taking place in the event structure.

Also, note that for me the Play Sound vi needed to be in a while loop to keep playing. Not sure why this is needed, but the NI examples sets it up this way (\examples\Graphics and Sound\Sound\Sound Player.vi).

Finally, you may crash the vi if your sound card gets overwhelmed as mentioned [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/lvsound2-dll-continuous-sound-input-read-vi-hanging-issue/td-p/1772376). If that happens I would go with a better sound library to try and squeeze more performance out of your sound card.

[image]

### Original:

First, I assume you a referring to [this Launchpad](http://global.novationmusic.com/launch/launchpad#)?

I was able to press up to 4 keys at once will the following - the important thing is to set the event timeout to 1 ms. If you need more than that it will require a more sophisticated design.

I was no able to easily implement a sound because all the basic LabVIEW beeps are what's considered "blocking I/O" meaning if you call 2 Beeps simultaneously than Windows will play one after another not both at the same time. You will need to implement you instrument notes using [non blocking I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) probably in a language other than LabVIEW such as this [C++ library](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/).

[image]

Comment: Yes, Im trying to do some like this. Thank You for answer if I not find any other possibility, I will use C++ library to solve this.

Comment: What exactly does setting the timeout to 1 ms accomplish here? Also, this does not demonstrate playing multiple sounds at once, which I believe is what the OP is looking for.